# routing error: Passing a parameter to an action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, parameter-passing, rails-routing, link-to

My model summary: A user has many appointments. An appointment has many bookings. A Booking belongs to an appointment.

I'm trying to link_to a specific view (called "users_bookings") that lists all the bookings for a specific appointment. Here is what I have tried:

```
<% current_user.appointments.each do |appointment|%>
    <%= link_to "view all bookings", users_bookings_appointment_booking_path(appointment)%>
<%end%>
```

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `users_bookings_appointment_bookings'
```

Additional Info:

Routes:

```
resources :appointments do
    resources :bookings do
      get 'users_bookings', :on => :collection
    end        
  end
```

Bookings Controller create Action:

```
def create
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:booking][:appointment_id])
    @booking = @appointment.bookings.new(params[:booking])
```

Bookings controller Users_bookings Action:

```
def users_bookings
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:booking][:appointment_id])
    @bookings = @appointment.bookings.all
end
```

Users_bookings view:

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
    <td><%= booking.appointment_date%></td>
    <td><%= booking.start_time %></td>
    <td><%= booking.end_time %></td>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `match` (as others have suggested) unless you really want to match *all* HTTP requests (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) for that URL. Instead, just add a route to the resource in the `do` block:

```
resources :appointments do
  resources :bookings do
    get 'user_bookings', :on => :collection
  end
end
```

This will add an additional route for a `GET` request to `/appointments/:appointment_id/bookings/user_bookings' and route it to 'bookings#user_bookings'.

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to be the index action of the bookings controller. That way it would match '/appointments/1/bookings'.

However if there's a reason you can't do that, as it's not one of the standard routes you'll need to specify it in the routes.rb file. Something like:

```
match '/appointments/:id/bookings/users_bookings' => 'bookings#users_bookings'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to define a custom route which points to the defined action in your controller, such as:

```
match 'appointments/:id/users_bookings' => 'bookings#users_bookings', :as => :users_bookings
```

the resourcefull routes just relieve you from the burden of typing the standard routes for the CRUD-actions but can be extended with custom routes, in example if you want to offer a download link for a PDF or CSV export of a resource object

you can then use users_bookings_path in your view file to point to the action